# PrintServer (PDF) which archives tray selection meta data

Tags: pdf, self-hosted, printing, archiving

PDF does not contain information about tray selection.

You need to store this side-by-side the pdf file.

Unfortunately cups (which we use up to now) does not support the archiving of this meta data.

See related issue: https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/4968

Up to now I found [Pykota](http://www.pykota.com/) but the home page looks very dated. Most information is roughly ten years old.

Required features:

- printing system like [CUPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS) (or plugin for CUPS)
- beside printing the jobs need to get archived including the meta data
- open source - self hosting
- archive tray selection of the files which get printed

With meta data I mean:

- like tray selection
- user information (if available)
- date+time

Comment: In PostScript you can use the *setpagedevice* command to select items from the PPD as discussed [here](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.lang.postscript/2008-06/msg00020.html), so you might see if you can embed something similar in a PDF, at worse by converting it to and from PostScript.

Comment: @meuh I had this idea before asking here. I asked the cups people about tray selection information in PDF. Here is the answer: https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/4964 ... I guess they are right. This information should be carried along in a second file.